# excel, applying functions to target ranges

Tags: excel

Is there a way in excel to apply functions to input ranges of other functions, so for exampel, if I have a column B with values and column A with strings and I want to sum all values in B where the first three characters in A are abc. Can I do this without creating another column with the first three characters of A. Something like
    sumifs(B:B,left(A:A,3),"abc")

I am looking to do this without creating my own functions in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you can use a wildcard match:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"abc*")
```

To answer your more general question, if you absolutely need to select rows based on a formula, but you absolutely can't add any columns, you could use an array function, but that can be problematic in a case like this.  This would be a BAD IMPLEMENTATION:

```
REALLY SLOW:
{=SUM(B:B*(LEFT(A:A,3)="abc"))}  entered without the brackets, pressing ctrl+shift+enter for an array formula
    or:
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B*(LEFT(A:A,3)="abc"))  abusing sumproduct to get an array formula
```

It would have very poor performance, since A:A and B:B would be converted to very large arrays rather than ranges, and dragging the formula down even a few dozen rows would be excruciating.

This would have better performance:

```
{=SUM(B$1:B$100*(LEFT(A$1:A$100,3)="abc"))}
    or:
=SUMPRODUCT(B$1:B$100*(LEFT(A$1:A$100,3)="abc"))
```

replacing 100 with some reasonable upper limit for your row count. If you really need to row count to be dynamic, there are ways to work around it. You could, for instance, format your data as a table and use structured references.  You could also use something like this:

```
{=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)*(LEFT(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1),3)="abc"))}
    or:
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)*(LEFT(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1),3)="abc"))
```

which is ugly but functional. (The $A:$A reference given to counta can be any guaranteed-non-blank column in your table.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That s a great overview